# MySQL Workbench Execution Problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I install MySQL Server, and MySQL Workbench. I try to run the Workbench, and an error window appears with the title: [image: MySQL Workbench Execution Problem]

Comment: What is the name of the DATABASE?

Comment: The message seems pretty clear. Your database name or the path to it have non ascii characters. Please share that information.

Comment: Oh, sorry to bother you guys, I think I have ADHD

Comment: Thanks for help.